# Clarification on Google Workspace and Apps Script Quotas and Limits

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets-api, google-workspace, execution-time, quota

I have been working on a project where I use Google Workspace and Google Apps Script to edit spreadsheets. While I have gone through the official documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas), I still have some questions regarding the quotas and limits associated with these services. I hope someone with experience in this area can provide some clarification:

1. **Maximum Number of API Calls (POST) per day:**

I am trying to understand the daily limit on the number of API calls (specifically POST requests) that I can make when using Google Apps Script to edit Google Sheets. Having this information is crucial for effective script management.

2. **Maximum Allowed Execution Time for the Script:**

Could someone please provide clarity on the maximum duration for which an Apps Script can run? Knowing this limit is essential for planning and optimizing the execution of my scripts.

3. **Reset Timing for Execution Time Limit:**

I would like to know when the execution time limit resets. Does it start at a specific time, such as 12:01 AM, or does it reset upon the first API (POST) call made after reaching the limit? Understanding the timing of the reset is crucial for scheduling and managing my scripts effectively.

I would greatly appreciate any insights or experiences you can share regarding these quotas and limits. Clearing up these uncertainties will help me ensure the smooth operation of my Apps Script within the established guidelines.

Thank you in advance for your assistance!

I read the documentation and different pages but no help

Answer (score 0):

Based on my interpretation of the [docs](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas),

> Maximum Number of API Calls (POST) per day:

- This is the `UrlFetch` call quota. It is documented as 20,000/day[100,000 / day for paid]

> Maximum Allowed Execution Time for the Script:

- Each script can run exactly 6 minutes maximum(or 30s, if run as custom function or workspace addon).
- There is no documented limit for the "total duration"(i.e., multiple runs of 6 minutes), if script is run manually.
- The documented limit for the "total duration"(i.e., multiple runs of 6 minutes) is 90 min / day[6 hr / day for paid], if script is run through triggers, i.e., Triggers total runtime

> Reset Timing for Execution Time Limit:

- Docs say

> Quotas are per user and reset 24 hours after the first request.